# Telegram Python Bot which explains certain acronyms using arguments in the command

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to create a Telegram bot which explains certain acronyms. I want to use it in a group chat, thats why I thought about using it like: /acronyms blabla. I'm able to use the arguments passed via the command. I want to add the explanation to the given argument like this.

```
def acronym(update, context):
command = "".join(context.args)
acronyms = [
    "text one",
    "text two"
]
if command == "2B":
    answer = acronyms[0]
else:
    answer = acronyms[1]
update.message.reply_text(answer, parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN_V2)
```

How am I able to pass an argument and make a comparison to get the correct explanation? Since the command should be used in the group like /acronym 2B it doesnt make sense to use a Menu like the InlineKeyboardButton. I feel like the CallbackQueryHandler could be helpful but I cant wrap my head around how to use it without a Menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a dictionary to store the acronyms and the explanations

```
  myDictionary = { "acro1": "expl1", "acro2": "expl2"}
```

Each time the bot receives a command, search for the respective key:

```
for key in myDictionary:
    if key == command:
        answer=myDictionary[key]
```

Comment: It seems that the dynamic inserting of an answer is resulting in some sort of error. 
`File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 330, in post
    result = self._request_wrapper('POST', url,
  File "C:\Users\--\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\telegram\utils\request.py", line 244, in _request_wrapper
    raise BadRequest(message)
telegram.error.BadRequest: Can't parse entities: character '.' is reserved and must be escaped with the preceding '\'´`

Comment: okay i got rid of the error by deleting the parse mode option